# Enforce scrolling div element to stop

Tags: javascript

I have a list and I would like stop the scrolling div at some moment.
I have try to set the scroll to the max and it would fire scroll stop event.
But it seems that browser would keep the scrolling momentum event after the scrolling bar is hit the max.
Here is snip of my code.
Basically I would like to perform discrete steps affect which trigger by scroll.
When I scroll to the step, I would like to stop the scrolling immediately for listening next scrolling event.

```
function scrollHandle(event) {
    console.log("scrolling");
    if (!isScroll && currStep !== step) {
      if (useCaseTitleList.scrollLeft > lastPoint) {
        direction = true;
      } else {
        direction = false;
      }
      transitionUseCase();

      // enableScroll();
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("scroll start");
    }

    isScroll = true;
    if (currStep !== step) {
      if (!direction) {
        while (useCaseTitleList.scrollLeft != 0) {
          useCaseTitleList.scrollLeft = 0;
        }
      } else {
        while (useCaseTitleList.scrollLeft != maxScrollLeft) {
          useCaseTitleList.scrollLeft = maxScrollLeft;
        }
      }
    }

    if (scrollTimer != -1) {
      clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    }

    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("scroll stop");
      isScroll = false;
      lastPoint = useCaseTitleList.scrollLeft;
      currStep = step;
      useCaseTitleList.scrollLeft = titlePosition;
    }, 500);
  };

  useCaseTitleList.onscroll = scrollHandle;
```

========= .
I have tried set div overflow to hidden and change back to auto.
The momentum is still keep moving.

```
var isScroll = false;
  function scrollHandle(event) {

    if (!isScroll && currStep === step) {
      if (useCaseSection.scrollTop > lastPoint) {
        direction = true;
      } else {
        direction = false;
      }
      transitionUseCase();

      // enableScroll();
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("scroll start");
    }
    isScroll = true;
    if (scrollTimer != -1) {
      clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    }

    console.log(currStep, step, scrollDestination, useCaseSection.scrollTop);
    if (currStep !== step && Math.abs(scrollDestination - useCaseSection.scrollTop) < 200) {
      useCaseSection.style.overflow = "hidden";
      console.log("stop", useCaseSection.style.overflow);
    }

    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("scrollTimer", isScroll);
      isScroll = false;
      lastPoint = useCaseSection.scrollTop;
      useCaseSection.style.overflow = "hidden auto";
      currStep = step;
    }, 100);
  };

  useCaseSection.onscroll = scrollHandle;
```